# C - Using fscanf to read '-1' from a file

Tags: c, eof, scanf

I'm a bit new to C, but basically I have a problem where I need to read '-1' from a file. Sadly this means I run into a premature ending of the file, because the EOF constant is also -1 in my compiler.

What sort of work arounds would there be for this? Is there another function I can use to read it that will change the EOF to something I can work with?

Thanks in advance.

The code since people are asking for it

```
int read() {
    int returnVal; // The value which we return

    // Open the file if it isn't already opened
    if (file == NULL) {
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
    }

    // Read the number from the file
    fscanf(file, "%i", &returnVal);

    // Return this number
    return returnVal;
}
```

This number is then later compared to EOF.

Okay this is probably bad practice, but I changed the code to the following

```
int readValue() {
    int returnVal; // The value which we return

    // Open the file if it isn't already opened
    if (file == NULL) {
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
    }

    // Read the number from the file
    fscanf(file, "%i", &returnVal);

    if (feof(file)) {
        fclose(file);
        return -1000;
    }

    // Return this number
    return returnVal;
}
```

Because I knew I would never read any such number from my file (they range from about [-300, 300]. Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: It does not matter that the EOF constant is -1... there should never be a case of you examining the value you've read and it returning as -1 for any reason other than -1 was there (or nothing was read and your memory happened to contain -1 already). Post the code you think you're having trouble with and you can be helped, but without that, this question is incomplete by Stack Overflow standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of fscanf is NOT the value that was read, but rather it is the number of items successfully read, or EOF if an error occurred.

Comment: @Mildan `fscanf` provides at least *two* values: the function status as its return value, and the value(s) specified by the format requirement(s) / pointer argument(s). Have a good read of the man page. You should always check the return value of the `scanf` family as well as the range of the values of interest.

Comment: So I should add a check to see if fscanf returns < 0 item(s), and if it doesn't then it would have read an empty line and therefor EOF?

Comment: @Mildan you check whether it returns the number of items you wanted to be read, in this case `1`. If it doesn't you'll need a fallback strategy, or as the other answer, pass it back to the caller by making it `int readval(int* returnVal)` and of course changing the `fscanf` argument from `&returnVal` to `returnVal` and instead of returning `returnVal` you would return the return value from `fscanf`. Confused? Don't use identifiers like `read` or `returnVal`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `read` function doesn't distinguish between a successful read and an error condition.  You should change it to accept a `int *` as a parameter that `scanf` writes into, and the function should return something like 0 on a successful read and -1 on error.  You can use the return value of `scanf` as the basis of what your function returns.

Also, there's a system call named `read`, so you should really name it something else.  And don't forget to `fclose(file)` at the end of the function, otherwise   you're leaking file descriptors.

Comment: I will try them both ;)